# Does PHP support named closures?

Tags: php, closures

PHP has terminological interference by applying term "closure" to "anonymous functions".

Does this language allows [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) in non-anonymous functions?

Comment: It may help to get some feedback if you show what you would like to achieve and where php seems to not work for you.

Comment: You can assign an anonymous function to a variable and call it like a closure. So it is something like a named closure.